# Не удается результат работы формы записать в json файл

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть форма голосования, результаты которой хочу передать в `json` файлик. 
Ошибок не получаю, но даныне не записываются. Что делаю не правильно?

```js
var form = $('#vote');
form.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'poll-vote.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      myJson: JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray()),
      fileName: 'poll.json'
    },
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="vote" action="#" method="POST">
  <h2>Вопрос 1</h2>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="count" value="4">
  <div class="answers">
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="poll" value="1">ответ 1</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="poll" value="2">ответ 2</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="poll" value="3">ответ 3</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="poll" value="4">ответ 4</label></div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Голосовать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Покажите скрипт, который обрабатывает переданные данные на сервере. Пока непонятно, в чем проблема

Comment: Спасибо, @NPreston, дело было в сервере